# WooCommerce - Percentage Discount in products categories widget

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, woocommerce

I need to custom the output of Woocommerce Products Categories Widget showing the percentage discount for that category (Discount_Price*100/Standard_Price).
I can easily create a function that takes from the first product of that category:

- Discount Price
- Standard Price

and calculate the percentage discount, but I don't know how to show it in the output of the widget like this:

- First Category (50% discount)
- Second Category (30% discount)

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only entry point is the filter [`woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/2.0.13/classes/widgets/class-wc-widget-product-categories.php#L135). The output is done via `wp_list_categories` and I guess you'll have to do a [custom walker](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2bwp_list_categories%20%2bwalker) to achieve what you want. Or duplicate the widget code and make your custom one.

Comment: It seems that the problem is wp_list_categories because the Woocommerce Products Categories Widget makes all the work showing product categories in the right way but at this point:
    echo '<ul class="product-categories">';
    wp_list_categories( apply_filters('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', $cat_args ) );
    echo '</ul>';
it uses wp_list_categories.
So will be great to customize only wp_list_categories showing wht I need...

Comment: Well, try something and see what you get. See [ask].